# Quickly message box

Tags: application-development, gtk, pygtk

How can I make messages like this using Quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [Gtk.MessageDialog](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmessagedialog.html).

Example:

```
md = gtk.MessageDialog(self, 
    gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, 
    gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Download completed")
md.run()
```

You can find extensive information on using these dialogs on [this page](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/dialogs/).

Comment: I got error: NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#messagedialog